# How to make rollup use a mocked filesystem when running tests in jest?

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs, ts-jest, rollup

I'm writing tests for my rollup plugin and I'm mocking the fs module using `memfs` to use in memory files, here's a sample test:

```js
import { describe, expect, jest, test } from "@jest/globals";
import memfs from "memfs";
import {
  InputOptions,
  OutputAsset,
  OutputChunk,
  OutputOptions,
  rollup,
} from "rollup";
import { externalAssets } from "../src";

jest.mock("fs", () => memfs.fs);
jest.mock("fs/promises", () => memfs.fs.promises);

async function build(inputOptions: InputOptions, outputOptions: OutputOptions) {
  const bundle = await rollup(inputOptions);
  try {
    const { output } = await bundle.generate(outputOptions);

    const chunks = output.filter(
      (file): file is OutputChunk => file.type === "chunk"
    );
    const assets = output.filter(
      (file): file is OutputAsset => file.type === "asset"
    );

    return { chunks, assets };
  } finally {
    await bundle.close();
  }
}

describe("produces correct import paths", () => {
  test("chunk and asset in same dir", async () => {
    memfs.vol.fromJSON({
      "assets/text.txt": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text",
      "src/index.js": `
      import txt from "../assets/text.txt";
      console.log(txt);
      `,
    });

    const { chunks } = await build(
      {
        input: "src/index.js",
        plugins: [externalAssets("assets/*")],
      },
      {
        assetFileNames: "[name][extname]",
        file: "index.js",
      }
    );

    expect(chunks).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(chunks[0].code).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

when I run this test, it fails with this error `RollupError: Could not resolve entry module "src/index.js"`,
what I get from this is that rollup is not using the mocked filesystem.

when I try to read src/index.js inside the test using the `fs` module, I get the file content as expected.

how would I make rollup use the mocked filesystem ?

Answer (score -1):

For anyone that has the same problem, just use [mock-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-fs)